# QGIS query tool with graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, query

I search a possibility to save querys, that other users can use them.

For example: 
I have a polygon layer with different columns:area, id and owner.
Now I want to search in my layer a specific owner or an id.
Normaly I use to query tool for that, but I want to pass the project to other users of my company. 
These users are not familiar in handling the query tool. Therefore I search an easier way for query, maybe with the graphical modeler?
But I´m new into the modeler and don´t know how to create a model, in which I can change my search parameters at the time I start the model.

Or is there any easier way for querys in QGIS? Can I save my querys in a project and hand it to other users?

Comment: For Queries do you mean to use to tool "Select by expression"?

Comment: If It is just a simple search you are looking for maybe a simple plugin like *Search Layers* can solve your problem.